# Does MinecraftEdu support mods?

Tags: minecraft-mods, minecraft-education-edition

I'm trying to have a lesson to teach a class to program with [ComputerCraft](http://www.computercraft.info/) [Turtles](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Turtle) using [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)).
*Except, not everybody in the classroom owns a Minecraft account, so this rules out vanilla methods.*

Does MinecraftEdu support modifications to the game?

---

Before anybody closes this as off topic, **I am not looking for steps or to troubleshoot. Just a simple 'yes' or 'no'.**
*And this question can be applied to any mod anyway.*

Also, this question is NOT for the [Vanilla](http://minecraft.net) version of Minecraft. It is for the [Education Edition](http://minecraftedu.com) of Minecraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MinecraftEdu supports Forge mods. You can add a host of pre-tested mods directly from the launcher but you can manually add any mods you want. Check the wiki for more details: http://services.minecraftedu.com/wiki/Taking_it_Further#Using_mods

In fact, the latest version of MinecraftEdu comes with ComputerCraft and the new beginner friendly ComputerCraftEdu (http://www.computercraftedu.com) included.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is with a third part such as Forge, there is no Minecraft marketplace available on Education Edition.